# How to replace const names instead of values in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my controller:

```
$model=new MForm;
    $list=MForm::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT form_name FROM m_form');
    var_dump($list);
```

It returns values of form_name(values are integer e.g 1, 2, 3 etc.)
I created const in my controller:

```
    const US=1;
    const Ru=2;
```

I need to show const names such as Ru instead of 2 in my view file when it 2(US instead of 1). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Define an array that contains all the constant in it like:

```
$const = [
  1 => 'US',
  2 => 'RU'
  // and so on
];
```

and use it like:

```
echo $const[$result['col_name']];
```

here **$result** contains the result of query and **col_name** is the column that returns 1,2,3 and so on.

Comment: It is returning null value

Comment: But, when I used following code it is working:$list=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
   ->select('form_name')->from(m_form')->queryRow();

Comment: When, I tried to use queryColumn and queryAll, they are returning null values

Answer (score 0):

Inside view put it inside a html element without any display Statement of PHP.

Hope it will work...